# Groupby in NumPy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

To avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157577), here is an example of what I need. Given the sorted integer input array
`[1 1 1 2 2 3]`, I would like to produce the following slices, together with their index:

> ```
> 0: slice(0,3)
> 1: slice(3,5)
> 2: slice(5,6)
> ```

(Both the index and the slice will be used to index/slice into some other arrays.)

I think this could be solved with the [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Partly because I am learning NumPy, and partly because [evidence suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651683/341970) that `groupby()` may be inefficient, I would like to do this in NumPy. The code below seems to do what I want.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

if __name__=='__main__':
    arr = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
    print(arr)
    mask = np.ediff1d(arr, to_begin=1, to_end=1)
    indices = np.where(mask)[0]
    for i in np.arange(indices.size-1):
        print('%d: slice(%d,%d)' % (i, indices[i], indices[i+1]))
```

Is there a cleaner / more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function [`scipy.ndimage.find_objects`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.find_objects.html#scipy.ndimage.find_objects) returns exactly the slices that you are looking for:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
>>> scipy.ndimage.find_objects(a)
[(slice(0, 3, None),), (slice(3, 5, None),), (slice(5, 6, None),)]
```

It's hard to make a fair timing comparison without knowing exactly how you are going to use these slices, but a quick test shows that this is about twice as fast as your strategy of using `np.ediff2d` followed by `np.where`.

A couple of general points on your code:

1. You use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with a single argument. This is the same as [`numpy.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) and it would be clearer in this case to use the latter.
2. But having made that change, you could use [`numpy.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html#numpy.flatnonzero) and so avoid the `[0]`.
3. It's pointless to create an array if you are only going to iterate over it. Better to use an iterator. So instead of:

   ```
   for i in np.arange(indices.size-1):
       print('%d: slice(%d,%d)' % (i, indices[i], indices[i+1]))
   ```

   you can write something like:

   ```
   for i, j in enumerate(zip(indices, indices[1:])):
       print('{}: {}'.format(i, slice(*j)))
   ```

   **In response to comment:** If you find the `zip` idiom unclear then you could encapsulate it:

   ```
   from future_builtins import zip     # Python 2 only

   def pairs(a):
       """Return an iterator over pairs of adjacent elements in a.

       >>> list(pairs([1, 2, 3, 4]))
       [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]

       """
       return zip(a[:-1], a[1:])
   ```

   and then the loop would become:

   ```
   for i, j in enumerate(pairs(indices)):
       print('{}: {}'.format(i, slice(*j)))
   ```

   which ought to be clear.

   A fancier alternative is to use the (undocumented) `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to make an array of pairs of adjacent elements without allocating a new array:

   ```
   from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

   def pairs(a):
       """Return array of pairs of adjacent elements in a.

       >>> pairs([1, 2, 3, 4])
       array([[1, 2],
              [2, 3],
              [3, 4]])

       """
       a = np.asarray(a)
       return as_strided(a, shape=(a.size - 1, 2), strides=a.strides * 2)
   ```

   The documented way to make such an array is `np.c_[indices[:-1], indices[1:]]` but that allocates a new array.